How to succesively filter by the elements of a vector supplied to a macro?
It might help to briefly explain that I'm trying to do some simulations with various sample sizes using a macro. So I do a number of simulations for each potential sample size.
I am supplying the samples sizes I want to compare as a vector to a macro and also the number of simulations (per sample size) I'd like - say 4 simulations per sample size (in reality it will be more).
I would like to filter out each simulation for each sample size. The code below filters out each simulation but I can't get it to filter out the sample size supplied as a vector to the macro ie currently I just pick out each simulation so for example it picks out all the values of simulation 1 across each sample size. I would like to have the filtering line be
where simno=&sim. AND n=n2;

where n2 is the i'th member of the _n vector of sample sizes - but that doesn't seem to work.
The code is a toy version of the real code of course. If I can fix this I can move on.
Many thanks for reading this. I hope  I have explained it clearly. Thanks in advance for any advice.
%macro subset(_n=, nsims=);


data Sims(drop=j);
do i = 1 to %sysfunc(countw(&_n));
 n = scan("&_n",i);
   do simno = 1 to &nsims;
      do j = 1 to n;
         output;
         end;
      end;
      end;
   stop;
   run;
run;


%do sim = 1 %to &nsims;
%do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&_n));

data FilterSims;
set Sims;
*n2 = scan("&_n",i) ;
where simno=&sim.;

%end;
%end;

%mend;
%subset(_n=%str(10,20,50),nsims=4);


Your example of filtering does not make much sense.  If you want to subset based on the values used to drive the generation then just only generate for the combinations your want.  If you want to filter based on some characteristics of the generated simulations then filter based on the values of the dataset variables, don't worry about the values passed into the generation phase.

I would say either totally separate the simulation step from the analysis step.  That is generate your giant simulation dataset first.  Then use the data in the dataset instead of macro variables to drive the analysis.  Or do the looping in macro code and generate one simulated dataset at a time which is then immediately processed by the analysis steps.

many thanks for your time and thoughts, Tom. I will give thought to how I can change my plans based on your, and Quentin's ideas. I guess maybe simulate the giant dataset outside of the macro and then pass each subset in turn to the macro which returns results that can be appended to an overall results data set. As I explain to Quentin the intended program is more complicated than the toy example I post involving predictor variables etc.

My original program works when I pass a single sample size to the macro. I "just" need to pass multiple sample sizes. I was hoping that might be possible then it would look tidy in that I pass the possible sample sizes, number of simulations, number of predictors and their correlations etc etc. Its such a shame that where simno=&sim. AND n=n2; doesnt work as that would be all I'd need.

I can't quite follow your question. The macro runs as written, but note that it overwrites the dataset FilterSims which each iteration of the %DO loop at the bottom, which is likely not what you intend.
If you were coding a non-macro version of the first step, I think it might look like:
data Sims;
  do n=10,20,50 ;
    do simno=1 to 4 ;
      do id=1 to n ; *this is your j variable ;
        output ;
      end ;
    end ;
  end ;
run ;

Is that right?
What would you want for the FilterSims step?  Is it something like:
data FilterSims ;
  set Sims ;
  where Simno=3 and n=20 ;
run ;

You could write a macro to do that, but note it will only output one FilterSims dataset.  Maybe something like:
%macro subset(_n=, nsims=, where=);

data Sims;
  do n=&_n ;
    do simno=1 to &nsims ;
      do id=1 to n ;
        output ;
      end ;
    end ;
  end ;
run ;

data FilterSims ;
  set Sims ;
  where &where;
run ;

%mend subset ;

%subset(_n=%str(10,20,50),nsims=4,where=Simno=3 and n=20)

But I'm still guessing that's still not a good solution for what you're doing.   If the goal of the macro is to make FilterSims, it doesn't have to make the whole Sims dataset first.
If you're running a simulation, you don't need to successively filter your data by each simulated sample.  Instead you can use BY group processing to analyze your Sims dataset.

thanks Quentin, for your useful comments. I will have to think about them. I do realise I am overwriting the data each time. In the real program I plan to do lots more programming on each filtered data set (defined by each combination of _n element/sample size and simulation) and successively append the results to a resutl data set. Sorry maybe I should have said that.

I did wonder re "by" programming but the analysis I plan is quite complicated involving cross validation etc so I'm not sure if just using "by" is possible (especially when I'm the programmer). I probably wouldn't want specific values of n and simno passed as arguments as I do want to filter each n/simno combination in turn (and then do the further analysis. thanks again

I am thinking thanks Quentin how far I can get with by (simno and n). As I maybe didn't make clear this is just a toy version that I hoped would get me the code I could implement in my real program. My real data set has lots more variables. The next step is to use proc surveyselect to split each simno/n subset into groups for cross validation. I think I might be able to use the strata subcommand for that rather than by.

If you are converting process that works when passed a single value then just add a %DO loop around the whole thing.
So if you have this working macro that takes as input one value for _N.
%macro subset(_n=, nsims=);
...
%mend;

Then make a new macro that instead takes a LIST (not a "vector") of values. Then use a %DO loop to call the other macro once for each value in the list.
%macro subset_list(_nlist=, nsims=);
  %local run_no;
  %do run_no = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&_nlist));
    %subset(_n=%scan(&_nlist,&run_no),nsims=&nsims)
  %end;
%mend;

Then you can call the new macro like this:
%subset_list(_nlist=10 20 50,nsims=4)

If you want to modify your existing macro you might just change the parameter name and then make a local macro variable with the original parameter name.
%macro subset(_nlist=, nsims=);
  %local run_no _n;
  %do run_no = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&_nlist));
    %let _n=%scan(&_nlist,&run_no);
    ... rest of original body ...
  %end;
%mend;


wow - thanks ever so much, Tom. This is so helpful. I think I've applied your suggestions to my code and it even seems to be working ! (answer: larger sample sizes give better answers who'd have thought ? lol). I'm not sure I fully understand what we've done but I will study your suggestions and also the helpful comments by Quentin over the next few days/weeks. Thanks again to both of you and Happy New Year.
